# if $f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$ is the power series of $f$, then $f$ is constant if

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disk centered at $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be  an analytic function. let $f = u +iv$, where $u,v$ are the real and imaginary parts  of $f$. If $f(z) = \sum_n a_n z^n$  is the power series of $f$, then $f$ is constant  if

Choose the correct statements:

1) $f$  is analytic

2) $u(1/2) \ge u(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$

3) The set {$ n\in \mathbb{N} \mid a_n = 0$ } is  infinite

4) For any closed curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{D}$,  $\int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)}{(z-a)^2} =0$ for all a $\in$ $\mathbb{D}$ with $|a| \ge 1/2$

My attempts :  option  1 is  true  by Cauchy-Riemann's theorem
 and option 4 is true   by Cauchy's residue theorem   as $\int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)}{(z-a)^2} = 2\pi i f'(z)$ where $f (z) =  1$,  and $f'(z) = 0$

I'm confused about   option 2 and option 3
Pliz help  me

Any hints/solution will be appreciated,,,

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: The function $f(z)=z$ has infinitely many $a_n$ equal to $0$.

Comment: Why would you say 1) is true?  You already know $f$ is analytic; not all analytic functions are constant.

Comment: thanks  Lulu but  what about option 2 ?

Comment: also @stupid option 1 is true since the series converges by the root test

Comment: @RobertIsrael..ya  by lioville theorem

Comment: okks Nice thinking @Zophikel

Comment: @Zophikel,,,can u give  hints  option 2?

Comment: Maximum Modules Principle of Louisvilles Theorem

Comment: $f$ is analytic because that is one of the hypotheses, not because of anything else.

Comment: The open mapping theorem shows that if $f$ is non constant and $U$ is an open set in $D$ then $f(D)$ is open. In particular, $\operatorname{re} f(D)$ is also open, so 2) cannot hold.